# Devise - External sign in form on homepage outside Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and Devise. I want to add a sign in form to my homepage which is not inside my Rails app.

So I just copied the HTML from the regular sign in form:

Then I generated my Devise controllers and changed the routes to:

```
scope '/auth' do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions'
    }
  end
```

At last I disabled forgery protection in my sessions controller:

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Now when I try this new form to sign in I get:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

and am redirected to the app's sign in page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you taken any steps to diagnose the problem like checking the logs? If so add them to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
protect_from_forgery except: :create
```

Comment: What are the security implications of this? There exists safer ways to do sign-on using an external domain.